# how to add a navigation controller to a view that is not the main view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, nib

im a beginner and trying to figure out how to work with nib properly.

I have a HomeViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StackTableViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) StackTableViewController *stackViewController;

- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender;


@end
```

HomeViewController.m:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        //
        _stackViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc]init];
    }

    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {

    //[self.navigationController showViewController:_stackViewController sender:self];
    [self presentViewController:_stackViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As you can see I'm modelling from the HomeViewController to StackTableViewController...

Now it works ok, but I want that StackTableViewController will be embedded in NavigationController...that I can put a cancel button in the top.

This is my StackTableViewController.m:

```
#import "StackTableViewController.h"

@interface StackTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navBar;

@end

@implementation StackTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}
```

What should I add to the viewDidLoad method that will embed the navBar in the tableview?

tnx

Comment: are you using storyboards for you app?

Comment: Try to present another instance of `UINavigationController` where you make the `_stackViewController` as a root VC.

Comment: no i don't use storyboard, I want to program for a while with nib and in the future go to storyboard @nburk

Comment: ok., that's fine, I am writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not need to declare `StackTableViewController` as a property of `HomeViewController`, just modify `goToStack` like so:

```
- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {
     StackTableViewController *stackViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init]; // shouldnt this get loaded from a NIB though???
    [self presentViewController:stackViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

About youer issue with `UINavigationController`, depending on your setup the `UINavigationController` is the base for a certain navigation stack within your app, so, if you're just building a simple app without a tab bar or another more complex interface, your `UINavigationController` might be the `rootViewController` of your application's main `UIWindow` (a *property* of your `AppDelegate`).

So, what you will have to do to get this setup to work is in `application:didFinishLaunchinWithOptions` of your `AppDelegate`, set the application's root window:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil]; // I assume you have a NIB file called HomeViewController
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController  = navigationController;
    return YES;
}
```

This will have the effect that the `HomeViewController` that you will see on application startup, is **embedded** within an instance of `UINavigationController`, which again is the `rootViewController` of your whole application.

Then again, you can modify `goToStack` to use this instance of `UINavigationController` *instead* of showing `stackViewController` modally:

```
- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {
     StackTableViewController *stackViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init]; // shouldnt this get loaded from a NIB though???
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:stackViewController animated:YES];
}
```

You can use `self.navigationController` here because `homeViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigaitonController`, so iOS will set this property for you.

Hope that helps! :)

**Update**:
If you don't want to have your `HomeViewController` embedded within the `UINavigationController`, just modify `goToStack` like so:

```
- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {
    StackTableViewController *stackViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init]; // shouldnt this get loaded from a NIB though???
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:stackViewController];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I don't want my home view controller to be embedded in a navigation controller too...just that the table view will be in it...so it will have a tab bar at the top

Comment: what did you mean in the comment // shouldnt this get loaded from a NIB though???. Should I do it differently? this is how it worked so this is why i did it :)

Comment: since you said you are using NIBs I assumed you would have created a NIB for `StackTableViewController` as well. if you did then you might want to call `StackTableViewController *stackTableViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];` instead of just `[[StackTableViewController alloc] init];`, otherwise it will load a plain `UITableView` without the customizations from your NIB file.